# remove duplicate nested list based on item in list

Tags: python, csv, duplicates, nested-lists

I have a CSV file and each time I update with data I mean rows .. two things now I want to do but can't.
How can I remove duplicate list based on this

Input:

```
[name , age , school]
[jack, 76, oxford ],
[march , 32, cfr],
[bee, 43, oi],
[jack ,15, iuy]
```

Output:

```
[name , age , school],
[jack, 76, oxford ],
[march , 32, cfr],
[bee, 43, oi]
```

NOTE: set(list) won't do anything to my case

as you can see the second jack didn't add to list _ that's what I want

and (second thing ) how can now when I receive new rows It checks if a name is there or not if there it won't add that new row otherwise it will add

Comment: create a empty set and for each row check name is in set or not. if name not in set add the name to set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Utilize `set` to keep track of the added names
2. Loop over the list items: 
   2.1. If current name not added 
   2.2. Add current item 
   2.3. Update set

```
original_list = [['name', 'age', 'school'],
['jack', '76', 'oxford '],
['march', '32', 'cfr'],
['bee', '43', 'oi'],
['jack', '15', 'iuy']]

added_names = set()
filtered_list = []
for item in original_list:
    current_name = item[0]
    if current_name not in added_names:
        filtered_list.append(item)
        added_names.add(current_name)

print(filtered_list)
```

Output:

```
['name', 'age', 'school'], 
['jack', '76', 'oxford '], 
['march', '32', 'cfr'], 
['bee', '43', 'oi']
```

To update, simply check if name already exists in set.

Comment: thanks alot..I clicked upvote but that what comes.. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_list = []

#beforeUpdating
for j in all_list:
    if j == csvlist[0] #considering all names are on index - 1:
        #cancel upload
        break
    
#AfterUpdating
for i in csvlist:
    all_list.append(i)
```

I can provide you this as you have not posted your code. Hope this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

First Csv File contain this value :

```
duplicated = [  ['name' , 'age' , 'school'],
                ['jack', 76, 'oxford' ],
                ['march' , 32, 'cfr'],
                ['bee', 43, 'oi'],
                ['jack' ,15, 'iuy'],
                ['name' , 'age' , 'school']
             ]
```

When You execute this code

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3.8.2    
import csv

duplicated = []
names = []
clear = []

with open('python.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        duplicated.append(row)

for i in duplicated:
    if i[0] not in names :
        names.append(i[0])

for i in duplicated:
    if i[0] in names and i not in clear :
        clear.append(i)
        names.remove(i[0])

for i in clear:
    print(i)
```

The Output Should be :

```
['nom', 'age', 'scholl']
['jack', '76', 'oxford']
['march', '32', 'cfr']
['bee', '43', 'oi']
['jack', '15', 'iuy']``
```

this what you want :)